# Pra que serve / Texto / em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu estava vendo se havia outro tipo de comentário em javaScript além do `//`  ou `/*  */`. Foi então que eu percebi, que quando eu tirei os asterisco de `/*  */` não retornou um erro, retornou exatamente o que eu tinha escrito, que no caso era `/ OI /`. Eu pesquisei e não achei pra que server isso. Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 2):

O que você escreveu foi uma [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), como exemplificado pelo comentário do @hkotsubo na pergunta. Tudo o que estiver entre `/  /` será interpretado como uma expressão regular no JavaScript, como `/[0-9]/g` para encontrar todos os dígitos que podem variar entre 0 a 9 dentro uma determinada `string`, por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou :)